# edit .htaccess and pass originel URL as varible

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi I want to rewrite my we site url to my home page and passed requested url parameters as a variable

my web site structure: `index | gallery | animals` 
URL: www.mysite/gallery/animal

`.htaccess` file in animal folder ::

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite/$1 [NC]
```

I want to get original URL or gallery/animal in my index.php file after the rewrite done ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [NC]
```

Now every URL that doesnt point to existing folder/file, will rewrite to index.php (in webroot folder). You can access original url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

**EDIT:**

Let's say this is our webroot:

```
/
-   dir/
    -   other-page.php
-   .htaccess
-   index.php
-   page.php
```

And here how it will work:

```
What user types (and sees in URL)                What server sees and runs:
   domain.com/                                      /index.php
   domain.com/index.php                             /index.php
   domain.com/page.php                              /page.php
   domain.com/dir/other-page.php                    /dir/other-page.php
   domain.com/dir/                                  /dir/
   domain.com/hello/world/                          /index.php
   domain.com/i-like-cookies                        /index.php
   domain.com/index.php/random/string               /index.php
   domain.com/dir/page.php                          /index.php
   domain.com/page.php?game=super-mario             /page.php?game=super-mario
   domain.com/random/path?page=10                   /index.php?page=10
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but this does not work page not redirecting to index page its stuck one http://www.mysite/gallery/animals

Comment: Rewriting is not redirecting. And you need to use `.htaccess` in webroot. And if directory exists and you still want rewriting then delete it or delete `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line

Comment: Sorry for wrong English 
Actually I want to show the load/show index page first when user request mysite/gallery/animals but I need to know what he has requested this code rewrite url perfectly
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite/$1 [NC]

But it lost original url 
 
I put .htaccess file in animal folder

Comment: What I showed in answer does this: `1. check if url points on existing file or directory`, `2. If not, load /index.php and run it`. And that's it. And inside `index.php` you can call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to check what exactly user typed in URL. And it doesn't change url for user, but it makes server behave as it would when user typed `/index.php` instead of for example `/any/random/path`

Comment: @user3469694 check edit, maybe you will understand now

Comment: its pointing existing directory and i am using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in webroot index file 
problem is your answer not rewriting url :(

Comment: As I said, if directory exists, delete `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line and it will rewrite

Comment: did it but it s wont work
its work with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite/$1 [NC] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will get only /
with RewriteRule .* /index.php [NC] not working :(